# Android Studio - Can't download Android Repository (IO exception while downloading manifest)

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

**I can't download anything through SDK Manager.**

This is a screenshot of the "SDK Update Sites" section on my SDK Manager with my mouse over the red error icon: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1kx4.png

By the way, even if I add a Custom Update Site, and it's http://google.com, it still can't download shit.

The workaround that I'm using to get the SDK Platforms/Tools is using the "sdkmanager.bat" from Command Line Tools (cmdline-tools), but that requires the effort to always keep in check of SDK updates and installing new ones by commands.

Also, I've encountered a similar problem (with no workarounds) that I think has the same unknown reason as the former downloading problem - upon opening a certain project, Grade Project Sync fails with these IOExceptions printed on the Build log:

```
IOException: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-4.xml
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
IOException: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-3.xml
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
IOException: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
IOException: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-1.xml
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
Failed to download any source lists!
IO exception while downloading manifest:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    <lots of exception lines>

IO exception while downloading manifest:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    <lots of exception lines>

IO exception while downloading manifest:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    <lots of exception lines>

Still waiting for package manifests to be fetched remotely.
```

I don't use a proxy and "No proxy" is checked on Android Studio settings. I've also tried opening Android Studio with admin privileges. Thank you for your time reading, I'm totally lost on this one...

Comment: Is file available from web browser https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-4.xml

Comment: @Style-7 Yes, it is.

Comment: check file gradle properties for proxy.http = etc.